# Creating particular symbol \tilde{x} in SymPy

Tags: python, latex, sympy, symbolic-math

I am using Pythons SymPy and am struggling to create a particular variable. Particularly $\tilde{x}$.

I know that I can place a hat on top of a variable in this fashion

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy import *

xhat= sym.symbols("\hat{x} ")
xhat
```

but it is not working for the tilde.

***Attempt 1***

```
xtilde, ytilde =  symbols("\tilde{x} \tilde{y}) ") # Create
xtilde # Print variable

ildex
```

***Attempt 2***

```
xtilde, ytilde =  symbols("\sim{x} \sim{y}) ") # Create
xtilde # Print variable

~x
```

***Attempt 3***

```
xtilde, ytilde =  symbols("\~{x} \~{y}) ") # Create
xtilde # Print variable

\~x
```

How does one add tilde on top of the variable in Sympy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this !

import sympy as sym

from sympy import *

sym.init_printing()

xtilde= sym.symbols("xtilde ")

xtilde